# How to pass pointer to CURL in struct to vector?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
CURL * myHandle;
(... some operations)
std::vector<curl_a> * crl = &program_data::getInstance().curl_acc[80];
crl->push_back({ myHandle,true }); //look at bottom
```

struct of push_back seems that:

```
struct curl_a {
    curl_a(){};
    curl_a(CURL * d, int &l) :data(d), logged(l){};
    CURL * data;
    bool logged;
};
```

//header.h (singleton pattern)

```
std::unordered_map <int, std::vector<curl_a>> curl_acc;
```

And tell me now, why push_back dont work ?
Compilator return error from structs.h (with struct above)

```
curl_a' : illegal member initialization: 'data' is not a base or member
```

Comment: [These error messages](http://ideone.com/Pj5fle) look more appropriate for the occasion.

Comment: `true` is not an `int&`. Do not pass by non-const reference things that are not meant to be non-const references. If you need a `bool`, [say so](http://ideone.com/19e6FS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you are calling your `curl_a` constructor with an invalid second argument.  You are passing `true` when the parameter clearly wants an l-value (reference).

Instead of initializing with a value of `true`, use an integer variable.

```
int x = 1;
crl->push_back({ myHandle, x });
```

Here is your example, but simplified using `int*` instead of `CURL*`: http://ideone.com/SzxESi

Here is an example using your failed attempt of using `true` as a parameter: http://ideone.com/HQtAaU